# How to set an altitude reference system in xamarin?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have to set the altitude reference system in xamarin ( using Xamarin.Essentials). How to do that? There is nothing much in documentation about this.

I am trying to get Location.altiude and want to set altitude reference system.

[image: Screnshot]

Comment: @HrishikeshGarud What so you mean by "....setting Altitude reference system....` ?

Comment: This- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.location.altitudereferencesystem?view=xamarin-essentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the `Location.AltitudeReferenceSystem` property you write code like this:

```cs
Xamarin.Essentials.Location lastKnownLocation = await Xamarin.Essentials.Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

lastKnownLocation.AltitudeReferenceSystem = Xamarin.Essentials.AltitudeReferenceSystem.Surface;
```

### WARNING

Please note that `Location.AltitudeReferenceSystem` is a feature added in **Xamarin.Essentials 1.6**. For more information check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/release-notes/1.6#other-features).

NOTE: Xamarin.Essentials 1.6 is at the moment of this post in pre-release state. In order to install/update-to this prerelease NuGet in your project you will have to check the Include Prerelease checkbox in the NuGetExplorer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could check the usage of the sample code below.

```
 public async void method()
    {
        var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
        location.AltitudeReferenceSystem = AltitudeReferenceSystem.Ellipsoid;

    }
```

Screenshot:
[image]